# Spawn SSH connection but check status?

Tags: go, ssh, connection, exit-code

I'm writing a program in Go that needs to call `ssh` as a subprocess, but then once the connection is set up, use it for other things. I'm trying to figure out how to check whether the connection has been set up properly. The issue is that I can't wait for the exit code, since the command doesn't exit until a successful connection, but if I don't wait, then it's possible that I'll fork the process and do other things but then the subprocess will encounter an error and die. What I need is a way to know that, after a certain point, the connection has been successfully established. For example, one option would be to have ssh establish the connection and then, after it's established, fork the process owning the connection and having the main process return with a success code. However, I can't figure out if `ssh` allows for this sort of behavior.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the [ssh package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh)?

Comment: Yes - this is a user-facing tool that needs to be able to read the normal global and local ssh configs, take command line flags, etc. It's *way* easier for me to just call out to the ssh binary for that.

Comment: Strange to say it is easier when you've already run in to such a basic problem. Seems a lot easier to just give your program its own config/flags that are appropriate for what it does and to not depend on the user having the ssh binary somewhere that is accessible to your program as well as the appropriate version.

Comment: ssh accepts a huge number of odd flags with different behavior, and it'd be crazy for me to try to support them all. Git, for example, has the `GIT_SSH`, which controls how git invokes ssh as a subprocess, for exactly this reason.

Comment: So if I understand correctly all you want to do is make sure there was no error in the ssh command setting up the connection? Seems the simplest solution would be to just try it by trying to run a command.

Comment: Yeah exactly. In any case, I figured it out - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In particular, I'm using "ControlMaster" connection multiplexing, having one ssh process act as a master which keeps the actual ssh connection open, and allows other connections to multiplex streams onto the connection.

First, do:

```
ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=/path/to/socket -o ControlPersist=yes \
    user@hostname true
```

The important part here is that `ControlPersist=yes` tells ssh to continue running in the background even after the main connection stream has closed. Executing `true` on the remote server causes it to connect, try executing a command, and return. Once this happens, if it was successful, ssh will return with a success exit code.

Then you can connect using non-master ssh processes:

```
ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=/path/to/socket user@hostname ...
```